# Is the set $\{X\sqrt{Y}, \sqrt{X}Y\}$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, transcendence-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are transcendental over some field $F$ (doesn't actually have to be $\mathbb{C}$, but I chose that for definiteness; I believe the answer will not depend on the exact field, as long as both $X$ and $Y$ are transcendental over $F$).

How would one go about proving that the set $\{X\sqrt{Y}, \sqrt{X}Y\}$ is algebraically independent over $F$, or finding an explicit algebraic dependence relation?

This is a special case of a more general question I have about whether having $\{\alpha, \beta\}$ and $\{\gamma, \delta\}$ algebraically *dependent* over $F$ implies that $\{\alpha\gamma, \beta\delta\}$ is also algebraically dependent over $F$.

Just choose $\alpha = X$, $\beta = \sqrt{X}$, $\gamma = \sqrt{Y}$, $\delta = Y$. (Note that choosing the reverse order for $\gamma, \delta$ will give the set $\{XY, \sqrt{XY}\}$ which is clearly algebraically dependent).

This isn't homework, but the question came to my mind and I tried finding an algebraic dependence relation without any success so far. Mostly my attempts consisted of squaring the expressions (getting $X^2Y, XY^2$) and trying to isolate $X$ and $Y$ in terms of these expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $a=X\sqrt{Y}$ and $b=\sqrt{X}Y$ satisfy a polynomial $p(a,b)=0$

Then lets map $X\mapsto u^2$ and $Y\mapsto v^2$.

Then we get that $p(u^2v,uv^2)=0$

Let $p_n$ be the homogeneous part of $p$ of degree $n$. Then $p_n(u^2v,uv^2)=u^nv^np_n(u,v)=0$. Therefore $p_n=0$ (for all $n$).

Hence $p=0$.

Comment: Why is $ u^nv^np_n(u, v)=0$?

Comment: @Bananach Successively pass to the quotient of the ring by the ideal of elements of larger order.